# Entity Framework How to see SQL statements for SaveChanges method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I used to use the context.Log for tracing LINQ to SQL generated SQL Statements as shown in [Sql Server Query Visualizer – Cannot see generated SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156124/sql-server-query-visualizer-cannot-see-generated-sql-query/11201832#11201832)

```
context.Log = new OutputWindowWriter();
```

For EF, is there anything similar and easy like the above approach?

Comment: EF Core solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56310854

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In general you can hook up the built-in tracer or any logger by simple

```
context.Database.Log = msg => Trace.WriteLine(msg);
```

in the DbContext constructor.
See more in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464.aspx#Log). Some other approaches from MS are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464) (all based on [DataContext.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property).

Talking about the [Clutch](http://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Clutch) solution mentioned by Nate, it doesn't work with EF v6 (see [this bug-report](https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Clutch/issues/4)).

REFERENCES

1. [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations (EF6 Onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464)
2. [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464.aspx#Log)

---

Comment: im having an issue where update throws an exception and the sql it's trying to execute does not make it into the log..

Comment: How can this the accepted answer, for a question referring Entity Framework 4.0, and all is mention here only works in EF 6?

Answer (score 14):

The Clutch.Diagnostics.EntityFramework (available in NuGet) works perfectly for me, and it's simpler than the EFTracingProvider.

UPDATE for EF 6:

> Starting with Entity Framework 6, anytime Entity Framework sends a command to the database this command can be intercepted by application code. This is most commonly used for logging SQL, but can also be used to modify or abort the command.
>
> Specifically, EF includes:
>   * A Log property for the context similar to DataContext.Log in LINQ to SQL.
>   * A mechanism to customize the content and formatting of the output sent to the log.
>   * Low-level building blocks for interception giving greater control/flexibility.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464

Comment: Wow, yeah, that was so much easier. Also no changes required to the rest of your source at all, which is nice. Good find!

Comment: OK, so maybe I am dumb, but how to use Clutch Diagnostics? I tried the suggestion from http://girl-programmer.blogspot.de/2013/03/logging-and-tracing-sql-queries-using.html, and it didn't work for me :( More info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995098/how-to-use-clutch-for-debugging-sql-statements-executed-by-the-entity-framework.

Comment: It seems, Clutch doesn't work with EF 6. See https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Clutch/issues/4

Answer (score 6):

The [EF Tracing Provider](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/) can output all SQL statements executed as traces.  You can also use it to add your own logging if you want.  Here's some code you could put in the constructor of your context class (this is for a DBContext, but the tweak to use ObjectContext should be pretty apparent):

```
// enable logging all queries executed by EF
var cx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext; // change to var cx = this; if using ObjectContext.
cx.EnableTracing();
cx.Connection.GetTracingConnections().ToList().ForEach(
    c =>
    {
        c.CommandExecuting += (s, e) => Log(e);
        c.CommandFailed += (s, e) => Log(e);
        c.CommandFinished += (s, e) => Log(e);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of solutions to this, but simplest in code is just call ToString() on the IQueryable of the LINQ statement.

```
var query = db.Employees.Where(x => x.ID = 1); //query will be an IQueryable object
var  sql = query.ToString();
```

This is only in EF4.1 on (previously calling ToTraceString on the  ObjectQuery was the way to achieve this).

Comment: Judo: Your solution only shows SELECTs. Jonathan Rupp's answer shows everything (INSERTs, UPDATEs).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Nate's answer for EF6, the `NLogCommandInterceptor` seen in [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464) only shows the CommandText.

If there was some particular parameter value that caused that commandText to fail, the parameters values aren't emitted to the log. In my case I wanted to log what values were causing Foreign Key violations.

This can be improved by altering NLogCommandInterceptor's `LogIfError` method like thus

```
private void LogIfError<TResult>(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
{
    if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
    {
        var commandDumper = new DbCommandDumper(command);
        Log.Warn(Command failed:\r\n{0}", commandDumper.GetLogDump());
        // Exception will get logged further up the stack
    }
}
```

where the [DbCommandDumper](https://github.com/neutmute/Cyclops/blob/master/Source/Cyclops/Instrumentation/DbCommandDumper.cs) class reconstructs the DbCommand into TSQL that can be replayed into a test database.

Comment: For those seeking the "modern" (2017+ / asp.net core) way of doing things: This comment by fiat is what you are looking for.

Comment: Addendum: For those that want to dwelve deeper read this https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/14/ef6-sql-logging-part-3-interception-building-blocks/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use ToTraceString method of the ObjectQuery instance you have.
Another approach would be to look at the IntelliTrace of Visual Studion as it logs SQL going out of your project.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express - IntelliTrace is not there, I think